What would the downsides be of using [[no_unique_address]] all over the place?
[[no_unique_address]] allows structs to be more efficiently laid out, by sometimes putting members into tail padding of preceding members. We all like to save RAM and have more cache-efficient structs. So why not use it everywhere, all the time?
With reference to the C++ standard and/or the Itanium C++ ABI, what reasons are there to avoid using [[no_unique_address]] on most or all members?
For example:

Are there safety issues with this, like concerns about overwriting the object in the tail padding when using operator=? This answer implies maybe yes, but it's not clear whether it's a bug in the implementation of std::copy and also I can't reproduce it with modern clang.
I haven't found anything in the standard that says operator= is liable to cause a problem here. Also it seems like any problem with [[no_unique_address]] would also apply to base classes into whose tail padding subclass members are placed.

Are there efficiency concerns, like maybe requiring more code to load or store values? Given that the alignment is still correct I can't see why this would be the case.



I came to this question while pondering why libc++'s std::variant doesn't use [[no_unique_address]] for its state, meaning I can't use it in a struct that needs to be layed out efficiently into another and can do better with an open-coded union and tag. It's not clear to me whether [[no_unique_address]] could be safely used in std::variant assuming we don't care about an ABI change. But I'm interested in the wider question of what the downsides are in general.

Because you need more assembly instructions to extract the data out of a tightly packed struct? If you can access 8 byte of data at an 8 byte aligned address, that's 1 instruction. If that's 4 bytes at one address and another 4 bytes in the next address, you need 2 loads and 1 instruction to combine both. Don't you?

I'm not talking about packed structs, I'm talking about using [[no_unique_address]] to allow placement of following members into tail padding. As mentioned in the question I don't think this affects alignment.

You can get a pointer or reference to the item stored in a variant. That requires it to have a unique address. The attribute is more useful for things like an allocator that is empty and never has its address exposed.

There are definitely cases where the behavior of a well defined program can become unspecified by adding [[no_unique_address]]. A somewhat contrived example I could come up with:
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

struct X {
    [[no_unique_address]] std::greater<> g;
    [[no_unique_address]] std::less<> l;
};

void
foo(auto const& comp1, auto const& comp2) {
    if(static_cast<void const*>(&comp1) == static_cast<void const*>(&comp2)) {
        std::cout << comp1(10, 5);
    } else {
        std::cout << comp1(10, 5) << comp2(5, 10);
    }
}

int main()
{
    X x;
    foo(x.l, x.g);
}

We're creating a struct with two different comparsion functors and passing them as parameters to a function. This function checks first if they're equal by comparing their address and if so only executes one, otherwise both.
With [[no_unique_address]] it's unspecified which branch this program will execute. But without, you can be guaranteed that it will execute the else branch.
So making [[no_unique_address]] the default might have broken some old code.

Thanks, that’s a helpful example and maybe explains the std::variant context. I’m also interested in the question of writing new code, where you don’t have to worry about behavior changes.
